# sequence of passing parameter

Tags: c#, webforms

```
public static bool SavePhoneInfo(int applicantId, string phoneType, string phoneNumber, string extensionNumber, bool isActive, int userID, out string msg)
{
   DataAccess dal = new DataAccess();
   return dal.SavePhoneInfo(applicantId, phoneType, phoneNumber, extensionNumber,isActive, userID, out msg);
}
```

I want to add a default value for extensionNumber parameter. where to add the parameter? before out string msg or after and what is the sequence of the passing parameter in c#?

Answer (score 3):

In C# you need to put default parameters to the end:

```
public static bool SavePhoneInfo(int applicantId, string phoneType, string phoneNumber,  bool isActive, int userID, out string msg, string extensionNumber = "Test")
{
   DataAccess dal = new DataAccess();
   return dal.SavePhoneInfo(applicantId, phoneType, phoneNumber, extensionNumber,isActive, userID, out msg);
}
```

[Optional arguments in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments)

Comment: @mohammadmazharulhoque I don't understand why you should change something in DB. I just show how to put default value to parameter of methods. If you call the method without putting anything in this parameter it will use default value